# What's the relationship between this Kotlin CoroutineScope and Dispatcher and CoroutineContext

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

[image]

As attached, the code (from Kodeco at [here](https://www.kodeco.com/1423941-kotlin-coroutines-tutorial-for-android-getting-started)) is in an Android Fragment, I was wondering what's the relationship of `Dispatchers.Main` between these two lines:

```
L63: private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + parentJob)
L68: coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { .. }
```

What by my understanding is, the `Dispatchers.Main` on L63 means the coroutineScope is bound to Main thread, and the `Dispatchers.Main` on L68 means the coroutine block will be run in Main thread.

But do I have to specify it twice? What if I don't do like this, for example, what happens if I change L68 to be like: `coroutineScope.launch {..}`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for this dumb question, I got it now like below:

```
L63: private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + parentJob)
```

This specifies a custom coroutine scope, and this scope has been bound to the Dispatchers.Main (the main thread, and let's ignore parentJob in this question).

`has bound to Dispatchers.Main` means: the coroutine started by this scope will run in main thread.

And on L68:

```
L68: coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { .. }
```

this specifies, again, the coroutine block will run in main thread.
So as for the `again` here, I mean, by looking into the source code of `launch` function, I found this:

```
val newContext = newCoroutineContext(context)
```

And there is a context combination in the function of `newCoroutineContext(context)` which looks like:

```
val combined = coroutineContext + context
```

which means add the L68's `Dispatchers.Main` onto the L63's `Dispatchers.Main`, owing to they are the same, so finally the coroutine block after L68 will run in the main thread.

So to answer my question: `what happens if I change L68 to be like: coroutineScope.launch {..}`, nothing will change, everything is exactly the same, since before and after, the coroutine block will run on main thread consistently.

But, what if we change the L68 like:

```
coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { .. }
```

Well, this time, the app will crash because of it's trying to update the UI from a worker thread:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
    Process: com.raywenderlich.snowy, PID: 8562
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

This is because, the L68's Dispatchers.IO overrode the L63's Main.

Just keep the question and my post for a while here, in case it could help someone like me had the same confuse.

Comment: I didn't expect it to crash, so the dispatcher can not be set to another than Main ?